# How can I use moduleFederationPlugin in nuxt app

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, webpack-5, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Dose be supported "webpack 5" and "[moduleFederationPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/)" in the latest version of nuxt?
if answer is no, how can I use this features in the nuxt ? or what is solution for make microfront in nuxtjs?
please help me, tnx

Comment: Hi . Thank you for your kind consideration.
I just realized that webpack5 is not supported
But this is a feature could that made it possible to launch a microfront at Nuxt, so what alternative is there to implement a microfront at Nuxt?

Comment: I'm not a MF expert but at the end, this is out of scope of Stackoverflow guidelines (to ask for tutorials). Also, MF can mean a lot of things depending on how you decide to build it. Meaning that the componentization that we use in Vue/Nuxt is already a MF by itself. Otherwise, you do have a lot of articles on Google speaking about those various approaches. You can maybe check this one: https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/8-different-ways-to-implement-micro-frontends-with-vue-js-308663f0d51c

Comment: My question has nothing to do with tutorial, it is a matter of introducing alternative tools
Yes, there are different ways to implement this; But I am looking for an alternative tool for this webpack's plugin
Anyone that work with this feature of webpack , knows what I need

Comment: It still falls under the `Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.` category. So, I cannot help more here besides recommending to Google it out as much as you can. Alternative tools to this Webpack5 will probably not exist tho, since Webpack is still the king for production released bundles. Maybe give a look to Parcel, Rollup or alike? You'll need to dive into some good amount of configuration IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack 5 is not yet supported. Will be with Nuxt3. As of `moduleFederationPlugin`, I'm not sure what this is.

You can check the progress to Nuxt3 here: https://preview.nuxtjs.org/v3/
The credentials are: `nuxt`/`nuxt`

---

#### Updated answer

Here is a bit more info and a link to a podcast show: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000162/8816585