# How to use microfrontends with Vue/Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I wanted to know how to use Microfrontends with Nuxt or at least Vue.
Is there a plug & play simple solution to have it working quickly?
I've heard about [Webpack's v5 ModuleFederationPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/) for example, is this a valid thing to start my Nuxt project?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[As of today](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/releases), Nuxt2 is still using Webpack4 so `ModuleFederationPlugin` will not be a possible solution.
Nuxt v3 will come with Webpack's v5 support and you'll probably be able to try it then. I also heard that the same could be used [with Vite](https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation) btw.

As a general answer, you need to understand that a Microfrontend is not something simple to do. It is more about how you do structure your app in the larger scope.
It's like having a micro-service on the backend: it can be done is multiple ways and it all depends of the needs of the company/team.

---

If you do create a Vue2 or Vue3 project with the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/), you'll still have Webpack v4. You can probably try to make the upgrade yourself if planning to use `ModuleFederationPlugin`.

As an alternative, there is [single-spa](https://github.com/single-spa/single-spa). This is a way of doing it (probably not the only one).
Here is a podcast show talking about the subject in depth: https://devchat.tv/views-on-vue/building-micro-frontends-with-lawrence-almeida-vue-160/
It may be relevant to understand the general way this is working and also the pro/cons.

If you're not satisfied with this approach, there are a lot of articles on the Web talking about Microfrontends and some Google-fu will be enough to give you an alternative way.