# How could I serve both Nuxt.js and Next.js divided by path?

Tags: vue.js, next.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js. To replace it with Next.js gradually, I want to use both Nuxt.js and Next.js divided by path, e.g, `www.mywebsite.com/path-for-nuxt-js` for Nuxt.js, `www.mywebsite.com/v2/path-for-next-js` for Next.js.

I don't expect to get a library solution or details. This is a kind of structure issue, and I wish to get some keywords or related links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable thanks to micro-frontends: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000162/8816585

I know there are some other packages/ways but this is a nice starting point. Doing that homemade could be quite complex IMO.