# Add Vue.js script tag to website which already uses Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a widget written in `Vue.js v2` which gets installed on 3rd party websites. It is something similar to those chat widgets which you come across on many websites.

It is created with `vue-cli` and is bundled into a single JS file. This allows 3rd party websites to install the widget via a single script tag pointing to the JS file, for example:

```html
<script async src="https://www.example.com/js/widget.js"></script>
```

Here is the section of my `vue.config.js` which bundles the app into a single JS file:

```
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: "js/widget.js",
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: false,
    },
  },
  css: {
    extract: false,
  },
```

Everything works correctly when installed on regular `HTML` websites or single page apps. The issue I'm noticing is when a 3rd party adds my widget onto a website which already has `Vue.js` added via a script tag, for example:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({
        ...
    })
</script>
```

So the 3rd party website is simply adding Vue to a single html page to do something. But on those pages, my widget breaks.

The error I get is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mutate')
```

I don't believe the exact error message is the important part. The underlying issue lies in installing a widget written in Vue onto an html page which also happens to have Vue added via a script tag.

Is it possible to have both on the same page? I don't have any control over where the widget is installed.

Comment: You could maybe have some kind of name spacing like a [micro-frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000162/8816585) works. You can also have it targetting a really specific id, like `#my-cool-widget`, less chance to get a collision overall. Otherwise, generating a web component from a Vue component could also be an approach, that way it's generic and not even depending on Vue itself.

Comment: why don't you try bundling your vue app? maybe then they won't collide with each other.

Comment: It's unknown how your app is bundled and structured. It shouldn't depend on external window.Vue.

Comment: could iframe be used? seems more safe to use iframe when using 3rd party scripts like this. Avoid collusion and ensure the web is safe from external modification.

Comment: @Kunukn iframes are quite clunky and not that performant tho, no? All the time I hear this word, my core web vitals + UX radar feels bad.

Comment: `Is it possible to have both on the same page?` it seems yes. I tested out the concept on my machine. One bundled and one from CDN. I tested different Vue 2 versions. If inside each other, then the inner was overridden.

Comment: @Kunukn that's interesting. I wonder why it's not working for me. I've added a section for my `vue.config.js` to the question which bundles the app into a single JS file. Not sure if that has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: @kissu thanks for the suggestion but I am already targeting a very specific unique ID.

Comment: @EstusFlask I've added a snippet from my `vue.config.js` to show how I bundle the app into a single JS file. I then simply build it using `vue-cli-service build`

Comment: There seems to be no obvious problem with config. The rest depends on your app, currently only you can access it. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . There's no such problem in general. "I don't believe the exact error message is the important part." - it is, you could track a place where it happens. Vue itself doesn't use `mutate` afaik, this may be specific to other libs in use, notably third-party Vue libs.