# How to have multiple vue applications in one project

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Where I work we have one .net web site with 3 different mvc areas which are for each type of user we work with.  Clients, Recruiters and Employees.  I'd like to recreate this in vue where it's one vue project but a separate client app, recruiter app and employee app.  Using the vue.config.js file I'm able to do that.

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,

  pages: {
    app1: {
      entry: 'src/clients/main.js',
      template: 'public/client.html',
      filename: 'client.html',
      title: 'Clients',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
    },
    app2: {
      entry: 'src/recruiters/main.js',
      template: 'public/recruiter.html',
      filename: 'recruiter.html',
      title: 'Recruiters',
      chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index']
    }
  }
})
```

This works fine when I build a production version of the site with the cli.  However I cannot get it to work properly when I run the local dev version.  Here's a screenshot of my project (using webstorm).
[image]

Before I set up all of the separate apps, when I would run vue-cli-service serve the public index.html file would get the main.js file from the src folder injected into it.  I am trying to get the same thing happening for the Clients and Recruiters folder where the recruiters/main.js file get injected into the public/recruiter.html file and so on for clients.  For now, I'm guessing because of the vue.config.js file, it no longer injects the src/main.js into the public/index.html file.

Is there a setting for the cli to do this?  Or a config file I'm missing?

Comment: Give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000162/8816585