# How to share basic UI component with Module Federation in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vite, webpack-module-federation

scenario:

Our team( Team-A) has a website (website-A) that implements by using vue.
Last Month our company set up another new team(Team-B) that inchagres of new customers.

Team-B will develop some vue application(component-B) which want to embed in our website-A.
After some discussion, we deside to use module federation.

The question is:

The team-B want to see the effect "how do component-b look when embed in website-A"
when coding.

[image]

How to achive this?

Now we plan to modify website-A's structure then provide some basic componet.
The team-B can use them by module federation then embed their component by slot.
In that case, team-B can see the UI effect when developing.

[image]

Is there any other better solution?

Comment: Not sure if this is helping/answering anything but here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000162/8816585