# How to package a Vue Single File component with Vite to load it via HTTPS?

Tags: vue.js, vite, vue-cli, vue-sfc

I'm trying to create a compiled an packaged version of my Vue Single File component to distribute and dynamically load it via HTTP.

I found [this article from Markus Oberlehner](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/) that uses Vue CLI v3 with the following command:

```
npx vue-cli-service build --target lib --formats umd-min --no-clean --dest server/components/MyComponent --name "MyComponent.[chunkhash]" server/components/MyComponent/MyComponent.vue
```

It seems to work fine, however, I would like to use Vite instead. Is that possible? Which is the equivalent command?

Comment: Hey! Author of the original article here. I recommend you look into Module Federation (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/). When I wrote the original article, it did not exist yet. Nowadays, I'd 100% go for Module Federation instead of rolling my own. There is also a Vite plugin for it: https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation

Comment: Didn't get it initially but we're talking about micro-frontends here. I have written an answer on that subject too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69000161/8816585 (with some details on how to do that well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Author of the original article here.

I recommend you look into [Module Federation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/). When I wrote the original article, it did not exist yet.   Nowadays, I'd 100% go for Module Federation instead of rolling my own.

There is also a Vite plugin for it: https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation