# Routing in two applications Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have two applications. app1 and app2.
app1 is a website [www.wxample.com](http://www.wxample.com). There is a button.
Is possible, when I click button to move to Login Panel in app2 to workers module?
I want add code only in app2.

This is the main page from routes.js

```
 {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('pages/Index')
  },
{
    path: '/app/workers',
    component: () => import('layouts/workers'),
    children: [
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: () => import('pages/workers/main')
      }
    ]
  },
... others components
```

This is one of many components from Index.vue:

```
{
   title: 'workers',
   moduleId: 123,
   intent: '/app/workers/main',
   loginType: 'uzt',
   icon: 'fas fa-user',
   active: true,
   beta: true
 }
```

Login Panel is popup. I using quasar framewoork.

I want to redirect user from app1 to app2 so he can login.

Comment: They appear to be the same app in the code you posted

Comment: Yes, it's code from app2. Do you know what should I do to redirect user from app1 to app2? I added new path in routes.js but didn't work, i can't catch userId and moduleId. Maybe is other way?

Comment: It's unclear what this is all about, you know your case but others don't, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . If they are totally different apps that are built differently then a router isn't supposed to help at all, at this point this isn't any different than redirecting a user to any random url, window.location has to be used

Comment: Do you want some [micro-frontend architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69000162/8816585) here? Not sure that it's needed but you can do that. Otherwise, you can maybe go from one app to the other by nuking the SPA (with `window.location`). But don't do that, it's bad.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `if` which checked the URL. If `true` then message the parameters. This approach worked but I have to edit this.