# The .native modifier for v-on is only valid on components but it was used on <a> tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, upgrade

I'm in the middle of a Vue3 migration and I'm not sure on how to fix this specific issue, it was working fine with Vue2.

> Error: [Vue warn] "The .native modifier for v-on is only valid on components but it was used on ."

Comment: Hi, where is the question? Please make it as Q&A.

Comment: Sry i can't find Q&A i'm just second post

Comment: If you want to answer to a specific issue, ask a question and answer it. Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69000161/8816585). Stackoverflow is not a blog platform, it's more of a question/answer platform.

Comment: ok thank you i'll learn it i'm sry

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following in your `main.js` file

```js
Vue.config.warnHandler = function(msg) {
  if (msg !== "The .native modifier for v-on is only valid on components but it was used on \<a\>.") {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.error(msg)
  }  
}
```

This is a preliminary solution that will catch the error in the preliminary work. Actually, it's not the best way to do it, it's really a good idea to modify elements that use `v-on` as `@` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you search your code you can't find where you have used `v-on` in your code.
That is because this happens when have used the  `@click.native` event modifier somewhere in your code.
Try to remove the `.natie` part from there and use only `@click` if it's possible with your requirement.
Just read more about the .native Event modifier before changing your code if you are in the middle of a version migration.